# Describe the polymorphic relationship of Django

Tags: django, django-orm

Tell me how to describe this connection:
[image]

There is a table in which there can be different types of records (Type1, Type2 or Type3).

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class General(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'General'

  class Type1(models.Model):
    name = GenericRelation(Product)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Type1'
```

How to make a connection and choose what I want to type in a type, for example Type2?

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct except the line:

```
name = GenericRelation(Product)
```

should be:

```
name = GenericRelation(General)
```

in order to form the correct reverse generic relation.